# Open an image using URI is missing icons on top when displayed

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following code to display an image that it's stored on my sd card:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/pp.jpg"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

This works ok, but it displays something like this:

[image]

If I open the image directly from my phone, it shows like this:

[image]

How can I show the rest of the icons that you see on top when I open it from my app? I need at least to show the share button. Thanks

Comment: You have to add these items in your menu.xml

Comment: you have to build them

Comment: I ended up using a webview. With a webview you already have zooming capabilities and that saves a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this intent, you are telling the OS to find an app that can handle opening an image and you're doing this without checking whether there even is an app to handle it. A 3rd party app is thus handling the intent and opening the image taking it out of your control. You could try and find the right intent or extras to get the desired effect from the 3rd party app, but it is unlikely that you will be able to get it and furthermore there are thousands of devices in Android land and each one could have a different app handling your intent.

In order to ensure the functionality is as desired, you should open the image in your own app and create a menu with the options you desire as bhargav instructed.

Also, you should start your intent like the following to be a little safer with it if you are still going to have 3rd party apps open your images.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/pp.jpg"), "image/*");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand better how it works now. Before trying to write my own, is there a way to open the image using the Gallery? If that could be possible, then maybe I wouldn't need to write my own.

Comment: There are probably over 25 commonly used gallery apps. Unless you're ok with saying, "Here is the image, just open it" and you don't need the gallery apps to do anything else then you would be OK, but if you're trying to ensure a specific user experience i.e. sharing the image etc. then you will need to implement your own 'gallery app' view within your own app. You are already doing what you need to do to have gallery open the image, but there is no telling whether a particular android user has gallery installed. They might have Google Photos only. Or some Samsung or LG version of gallery.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did.

Comment: There could be other answers so it's still early. I already gave you reputation. Also there is another answer that says exactly what you did. I don't understand why people demand and care about that so much. Some people seem to help only for that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new Activity with an ImageView in center. And add all your menu icons in your menu.xml file of this activity as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Single menu item 
         Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
    -->
    <item android:id="@+id/menu1"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu1"
          android:title="menu1" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu2"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu2"
          android:title="menu2" />

    .......
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the activity that is showing the image is nor your activity, you have no control over what, if any, options that activity gives the user. That activity was written by another developer, and that developer is free to do what she wants.

Moreover, there are thousands of Android device models. There will be hundreds of different image-viewing apps pre-installed on those device models, and there will thousands more available for download from places like the Play Store. The user will choose the app to view the image. What options, if any all those apps offer will be up to the thousands of developers who wrote those apps, not you.

If you want absolute control, write your own image-viewing activity.